# Running Selenium Webdriver script in Chrome

Tags: java, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run Selenium Webdriver script in Chrome, have added following lines in my existing script

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Garimaari\\IdeaProjects\\Webdriver testing\\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe");
    private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I am building my script in Intellij using Java. Not sure why i am getting  "can not resolve symbol setProperty". I tried changing JRE and JDK files but nothing has worked. Any help would be appreciated.

Adding code

```
public class StartCaseJava extends TestCase {

   private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
//  Getting Date and Timestamp for Last Name
    Date d = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyHHmmss");
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Garimaari\\IdeaProjects\\Webdriver testing\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
//        private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
//        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
//        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    public void testStartCaseJava() throws Exception {
//        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Garimaari\\IdeaProjects\\Webdriver testing\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Comment: Please check whether you have declared this in the correct format in your class, also if you post more info on the code structure you wrote it would be helpful to resolve. !!

Comment: Added my code. I need to figure out a place to declare Chromedriver. It does not work if i declare under main class. It works when i decalre under testStartCaseJava method. But then Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver(), driver can not be used anywhere except the same method.

Answer (score 0):

It's a long shot but should this

C:\Users\Garimaari\IdeaProjects\Webdriver testing\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

maybe be renamed to  C:\Users\Garimaari\IdeaProjects\Webdriver testing\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

or are the double back slashes actually a necessary feature?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of one missing '\' before chromedriver.exe in your setProperty string.

Try using :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Garimaari\\IdeaProjects\\Webdriver testing\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run my script using Chrome now. Here is the small sample declaration I used:

```
class StartCaseJAva {

    static WebDriver driver;

    public  void testcasejava()) {

        System.setProperty(path);
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
}
```